# Airflow templating renders attributes not intended to be rendered

Tags: python, airflow

My custom Airflow operator receives a list of file names as input. I want to:

1. Render these files
2. Save this list of file names to some operator's instance attribute

The problem is that I can't figure out how to keep the original file names - it seems that the list containing the file names gets rendered before instance variables assignment and file names get replaced by their rendered contents.

Here is the example code:

```
from typing import Sequence
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from pendulum import datetime

class RenderingOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("inputs_sql",)
    template_ext: Sequence[str] = (".sql",)

    def __init__(self, inputs_sql, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.inputs_sql_original = inputs_sql
        self.inputs_sql = inputs_sql

    def execute(self, context):

        print("self.inputs_sql_original gets rendered:")
        print(self.inputs_sql_original)
        print("self.inputs_sql gets rendered:")
        print(self.inputs_sql)

with DAG(
    dag_id="check_rendering"
) as dag:
    RenderingOperator(
        task_id="render_sql",
        inputs_sql=["query/query_0.sql"],
        dag=dag,
    )
```

The outputs printed:

```
self.inputs_sql_original gets rendered:
['select * from table\n']
self.inputs_sql gets rendered:
['select * from table\n']
```

Can you please suggest how can I keep both the original file names and rendered files?

PS If I use a string instead of a list for `inputs_sql` the original file names are preserved in `self.inputs_sql_original`.